# Creating new lists from user inputs (Cicles) - Python

Tags: python, list, function, while-loop

```
quarter1 = [0, "1-Course1", "2-Course2", "3-Course3", "4-Course4", "5-Course5"]
quarter2 = [0, "1-Course1", "2-Course2", "3-Course3", "4-Course4", "5-Course5"]

pick_q = int(raw_input("Pick a quarter: "))
    if pick_q == 1:
        assignment = 0
        courses = int(raw_input("How many courses would you like to enroll? "))
        print quarter1
        while assignment < courses:
            course = int(raw_input("Please select the course you'd like to enroll into(1-5): "))
            newlist = []
            chosen_assignment = quarter1[course]
            newlist.append(chosen_assignment) 
            assignment += 1
print newlist
```

So I'm trying to make this program where a student can enroll to different courses within an specific quarter. I only put in 2 quarter as an example.

The problem I'm having is that I want to create a new list from the courses the student chooses, for example if he wishes Course1, 2 and 3 then a new list should be able to print "You have enrolled to [Course1,Course2, Course3]"
However when I run this and try to print the newlist it comes up when only the last pick the user entered in this case [Course3] and not with the other previous picks.

It doesn't necessarily have to print a list, but the user should be able to choose from the original list and gather this information to create new list. I put in a zero starting the list so that the user can pick a number from the list index 1-5. I'm new at python and trying to figure this thing out. Thank you in advance!!

Any other recommendations are really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the newlist variable is being initialized again and again inside the loop. You simply need to declare it outside the loop.

```
quarter1 = [0, "1-Course1", "2-Course2", "3-Course3", "4-Course4", "5-ourse5"]
quarter2 = [0, "1-Course1", "2-Course2", "3-Course3", "4-Course4", "5-Course5"]
newlist = [] # Declare it outside
pick_q = int(raw_input("Pick a quarter: "))
if pick_q == 1:
    assignment = 0
    courses = int(raw_input("How many courses would you like to enroll? "))
    print quarter1
    while assignment < courses:
        course = int(raw_input("Please select the course you'd like to enroll into(1-5): "))
        chosen_assignment = quarter1[course]
        newlist.append(chosen_assignment) 
        assignment += 1
print newlist
```